# Extract emojis from Dataframe column and add them into a different Column of the same Dataframe Scala Spark

Tags: scala, dataframe, apache-spark, apache-spark-sql, emoji

I have the following dataframe

```
+----------------------------------
|______value______________________|
| I am going to school         |
| why are you crying         |
| You are not very good my friend |
```

I want to extract emoji in each row and insert those values into a new column of the same dataframe as follows

```
+-------------------------------------------------
|______value______________________|______emoji___|
| I am going to school         |            |
| why are you crying         |         |
--------------------------------------------------
```

I have the following code to filter the sentences with smileys in the value column.

```
kafkaTopicDataFrame.filter(regexp_extract(col("value"), raw"([\p{block=Emoticons},\p{block=Miscellaneous Symbols and Pictographs},\uD83E\uDD00-\uD83E\uDDFF])", 1) =!= "")
```

But I'm not sure how to insert a new column with smileys for respective rows using spark scala.

EDIT 2

if i want to make emoji column contain arrays of **distinct** emojis i wrote the following code

```
df.filter(
      regexp_extract(col("value"), raw"(\p{block=Emoticons})", 1) =!= ""
    ).withColumn(
      "emoji", array(regexp_replace(
        col("value"),raw"([^\p{block=Emoticons}|\p{block=Miscellaneous Symbols and Pictographs}|\uD83E\uDD00-\uD83E\uDDFF])",
        ""
      ))

    )
```

actual output

```
+-------------------------------------------------
|______value______________________|______emoji___|
| I am going to school       |    []   |
| why are you crying         |    []   |
--------------------------------------------------
```

Expected Output

```
+-------------------------------------------------
|______value______________________|______emoji___|
| I am going to school       |    []      |
| why are you crying         |    [,]   |
--------------------------------------------------
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can replace non-emoji characters with an empty string. Note the `^` at the beginning of the regex pattern, which matches characters that are not the specified characters.

```
val df2 = df.filter(
    regexp_extract($"value", raw"(\p{block=Emoticons})", 1) =!= ""
).withColumn(
    "emoji", 
    regexp_replace(
        col("value"), 
        raw"([^\p{block=Emoticons}\p{block=Miscellaneous Symbols and Pictographs}\uD83E\uDD00-\uD83E\uDDFF])", 
        ""
    )
)

df2.show(false)
+-------------------------------+-----+
|value                          |emoji|
+-------------------------------+-----+
|I am going to school         |   |
|why are you crying         | |
+-------------------------------+-----+
```

---

Edit:

```
val df2 = df.filter(
    regexp_extract(col("value"), raw"(\p{block=Emoticons})", 1) =!= ""
).withColumn(
    "emoji", 
    regexp_replace(
        col("value"),
        raw"([^\p{block=Emoticons}|\p{block=Miscellaneous Symbols and Pictographs}|\uD83E\uDD00-\uD83E\uDDFF])",
        ""
    )
).withColumn(
    "emoji", 
    regexp_replace(
        col("emoji"),
        raw"([\p{block=Emoticons}|\p{block=Miscellaneous Symbols and Pictographs}|\uD83E\uDD00-\uD83E\uDDFF])", 
        "$1 "
    )
).withColumn(
    "emoji", 
    split(trim(col("emoji")), " ")
)

df2.show(false)
+------------------------+--------+
|value                   |emoji   |
+------------------------+--------+
|I am going to school  |[]    |
|why are you crying  |[, ]|
+------------------------+--------+
```

Comment: with the given regex even , character is also identified as a regex. can I get rid of , from emoji arrays?

Comment: @user3279893 yes, actually the commas are not needed inside the regex pattern. See edited answer.

Comment: Is there a possiblity to get distinct values in each array?

Comment: There is no array. What do you mean?

Comment: I have edited the given code to get an array of emojis. but i am missing the comma in between the array elements. i have edited my question

Comment: @user3279893 see edit. A bit troublesome to split the emojis, but you can try my code.

Comment: comma issue is solved successfully. but still distinct element part is not happening

Comment: maybe `array_distinct(split(trim(col("emoji")), " "))`?